# How to customize magento views

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm learning magento and still trying to figure out which views are rendered when you go to a specific URL.

for an example if I go to the login screen which has the URL;

```
http://localhost/magento-sample/index.php/customer/account/login/
```

I have installed a theme on it and now the app\design\frontend has three folders as;

- base
- default
- mytheme

please help me to locate the rendering view.

thanks in advance

Comment: System > Configuration > Developer > (section "debug") > Template Path Hints (on website level/store view). it will show in frontend all blocks and where they are located. DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION!

Comment: i just foundout and answered the question before I saw this. Anyways thanks a lot :)

Comment: +1 for sharing your solution with the community after you found out ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys I found out a way to easily find out.

just go to;

```
admin panel> configuration > developer(left menu bottom most option) > debug
```

and set "Template Path Hints" to "yes"

This will give the directory path for all the views rendered on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

If by view you mean a template file then it is going to be

```
app/design/PackageName/ThemeName/template/customer/form/login.phtml
```